# Bootstrap Dropdown Multiselect Not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, multi-select

Can someone please help me. Dropdown is not working. I was supposed to add the multiselect option but I can't fix this. I've tried rearranging the css and js but it still won't work. Tried placing the scripts and stylesheets that is required and it still won't work.

[image: here is what i've been getting]

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#sample-sample').multiselect({
                buttonWidth: '400px',
                dropRight: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

```html
<select class="bootstrap-select" id="sample-sample" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
        <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
        <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
        <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
        <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
        <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
```

Comment: welcome to SO, try researching more about the browser console and what it displays

Comment: Please check if you have you added the `bootstrap-multiselect.css` or not ?

Comment: It seems to work here, doesn't it?  What exactly is the problem, that is, what did you expect it to do that it doesn't?